# Disambiguate [duplicate-proposal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We have a [duplicate-proposal](/questions/tagged/duplicate-proposal) tag (17 questions, no excerpt) which is ambiguously used for *proposals about duplicate questions*/*proposed duplicate questions* and *duplicate Area 51 site proposals*. I propose retagging the former to [duplicate-questions](/questions/tagged/duplicate-questions) and the latter to something less ambiguous, e.g. [duplicate-site-proposals](/questions/tagged/duplicate-site-proposals).

Comment: It seems that the oldest 4 questions in this tag are also tagged [[tag:area51]], which would imply that this tag originally referred to the latter, [duplicate-site-proposals] case.

Comment: @zcoop98, yep, but the name of the tag is, as the more recent questions show, too ambiguous in its current state. Thus the retag-request :)

Comment: Agreed! The tag name isn't immediately clear. I agree that a disambiguation is in order :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deed has been done. The old tag [duplicate-proposal](/questions/tagged/duplicate-proposal) no longer exists, and the new tag [duplicate-site-proposals](/questions/tagged/duplicate-site-proposals) has an excerpt:

> Questions about Area 51 site proposals which may be/are duplicates of other proposals or of already-existing sites. Note that Area 51 also has a dedicated meta site, Area 51 Discussions.

[One question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242685/improve-flagging-dialog-ui) was closed as a duplicate after getting bumped.